# Interpolation technique inpainting Opencv

Tags: opencv, interpolation

i'd like to know which interpolation method is used in inpainting function in [OPENCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) and how it works.

Thank you very much for every reply.

Answer (score 2):

The very link that you gave to the OpenCV docs tells what algorithms are used:

> INPAINT_NS Navier-Stokes based method.
>
> INPAINT_TELEA Method by Alexandru Telea [[Telea04]](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#telea04).

Here are links to papers on the two methods used
http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/2004/JGraphToolsTelea/2004JGraphToolsTelea.pdf
[http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bertozzi/papers/cvpr01.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ebertozzi/papers/cvpr01.pdf)

Comment: Thank you...i was not sure that was the interpolation method.

Comment: Your welcome. I posted links to papers on the two algorithms.